# kinect application to control the body movements of a person in real time.

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to create an app for the kinect but i really new to the kinect, 
The application in theory will to take as input two persons and one of the persons will control the movement of both. If person1 move the arms the same movement will be applied to person 2, person2 will have no effect on the output (only the head) any thoughts, is this possible?
Thank you in advance sorry for my English.

Comment: not really suited to this format, but look into openni and NITE. they provide skeletal tracking and an api for kinect

Comment: Kinect SDK v2 will track 6 people with their full 25 points skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.But Kinect might want an order of appearing in front of the Kinect for example the person one will always be the one who has the control over next person, the thing is for the second one you will have to omit the rest of the joints except the head and combine those two skeleton data(person one and two) into one. Then you can animate your own avatar or something.